# How to know on which socket is a processor core?

Tags: c, linux, 64-bit, multi-core

I have a dual socket 8 core system, 4 cores on one socket and the other 4 cores on the other socket. How can I find, which core is on which socket through `/proc/cpuinfo`. For example here, on which socket is the processor core 7?

```
processor   : 7
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 23
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5420  @ 2.50GHz
stepping    : 10
cpu MHz     : 2500.012
cache size  : 6144 KB
physical id : 1
siblings    : 4
core id     : 3
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 7
initial apicid  : 7
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr ...
bogomips    : 5000.08
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 38 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Comment: This article, https://secure.relien.com/support/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/66/0/show-the-number-of-cpu-cores-and-sockets-on-your-system, says its the physical_id parameter, so in this case, the processor core 7 is in socket 1.

Answer (score 2):

the "physical id" parameter will tells. you may turn to the following page for more detail. [Understanding Linux /proc/cpuinfo](http://www.richweb.com/cpu_info)